# SQLCLR custom aggregate with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-assembly, sqlclr, user-defined-aggregate

I have trouble understanding of how CLR User-Defined Aggregates work.

I have to create some custom CLR aggregates with multiple parameters.
The point is to get the value of the first parameter depending on the second.

For example, I have the following values in my table, and I need the oldest employee `Name` for each `Type`:

```
    Type   |   Name   |   Age   
--------------------------------
Manager    | emp 1    |   35    
Manager    | emp 2    |   42    
Developer  | emp 3    |   36    
Developer  | emp 4    |   45    
Developer  | emp 5    |   22
```

So I would like to write a query like this to get the result by using my assembly:

```
Select      Type, dbo.fOldestEmployee(Name, Age) AS [Name]
From        xxx
Group By    Type
```

This would respond :

```
    Type   |   Name   
----------------------
Manager    | emp 2     
Developer  | emp 4
```

It look like it's possible with a CLR User-Defined Aggregate, but I have difficulty finding a concrete example of this kind of implementation.

For the moment I have this.
I create a class to collect the datas, but how can I sort (or do other thing) to them?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined,
    IsInvariantToOrder = false, // order changes the result
    IsInvariantToNulls = false, // nulls change the result
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false, // duplicates change the result
    MaxByteSize = -1)]
public struct sOlder
{
    private List<MyData> _datas;

    public void Init()
    {
        _datas = new List<MyData>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString valueField, SqlInt32 ValueInt)
    {
        if (!valueField.IsNull && !ValueInt.IsNull)
        {
            _datas.Add(new MyData
            {
                ValField = valueField.Value,
                ValInt = ValueInt.Value
            });
        }
    }

    public void Merge (sOlder Group)
    {
        _datas.AddRange(Group._datas);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate ()
    {
        //...
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public String ValField { get; set; }
        public Int32 ValInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with aggregation, you simply need to write a statement that returns the oldest employee per type. There are a lot of ways to do it and all will perform faster than what you are trying to do. Check for example [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). If you partition by type and order by age descending, you are looking for entries with ROW_NUMBER 1

Comment: Thanks for the respond. We actually do this kind of treatment by statement or sql function. But this is just a lite exemple to understand how it's working.

Comment: And whe do this king of treatment on big volumes. And we improve a lot the performance by using for example this [Concatenate Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Select Type, MAX(Age) From xxx Group By Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to store a list of all the records - you only need to store the details of the oldest record you've seen so far.

Something like this should work:

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined,
    IsInvariantToOrder = true,
    IsInvariantToNulls = true,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = true,
    MaxByteSize = -1)]
public struct sOlder : IBinarySerialize
{
    private struct MyData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(MyData other)
        {
            if (Age == null) return other.Age == null ? 0 : -1;
            if (other.Age == null) return 1;
            return Age.Value.CompareTo(other.Age.Value);
        }

        public static bool operator <(MyData left, MyData right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) == -1;
        }

        public static bool operator >(MyData left, MyData right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) == 1;
        }
    }

    private MyData _eldestPerson;

    public void Init()
    {
        _eldestPerson = default(MyData);
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString name, SqlInt32 age)
    {
        if (!name.IsNull && !age.IsNull)
        {
            var currentPerson = new MyData
            {
                Name = name.Value,
                Age = age.Value
            };

            if (currentPerson > _eldestPerson)
            {
                _eldestPerson = currentPerson;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Merge (sOlder other)
    {
        if (other._eldestPerson > _eldestPerson)
        {
            _eldestPerson = other._eldestPerson;
        }
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        return _eldestPerson.Name;
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        if (_eldestPerson.Age.HasValue)
        {
            writer.Write(true);
            writer.Write(_eldestPerson.Age.Value);
            writer.Write(_eldestPerson.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.Write(false);
        }
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.ReadBoolean())
        {
            _eldestPerson.Age = reader.ReadInt32();
            _eldestPerson.Name = reader.ReadString();
        }
        else
        {
            _eldestPerson = default(MyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you create a struct for `MyData` instead of a class, don't you still need to specify `Format.UserDefined` and implement the `Read` and `Write` methods? I haven't tried it, but my reading of "Native" in [Format Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.format.aspx) indicates that it is due to the use of `string`.

Comment: @srutzky: You'd still need to use the `SqlUserDefinedAggregate` and `Serializable` attributes, as per the question. You'd also need to implement [the `IBinarySerialize` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Yes, I assumed the need for the attributes, but was just wondering if there was an implication here of being able to get away with _not_ implementing `IBinarySerialize`.

Comment: @srutzky: No, I agree with your interpretation of the docs. I've updated the answer with a basic implementation.

Comment: Thanks guys, work like a charm ! thanks for the explanation

Comment: @RichardDeeming: Could you take a look a this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267341/sqlclr-custom-aggregate-with-multiple-sql-variant-parameters) please. I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an implementation of your specific request, then @Richard's answer looks to be correct (though, you *might* still need to implement the `Read` and `Write` methods for using a custom type -- `Format.UserDefined`).

However, it seems from the comments on the question that this is more of a general question of when to do processing of whatever information you are collecting. In that case:

- The `Accumulate` method is called **for every row** in a particular GROUP. This is the entry point.
- The `Merge` method is called **when parallelism is being used**. SQL Server uses this method to combine the information from various threads. Depending on the type of algorithm you are doing, here you might: combine the current and incoming information, decide to keep the current info or the incoming info (as is being done in @Richard's implementation), recalculate the current info based on the new incoming info.
- The `Terminate` method is called **at the end of each particular GROUP**. Here is where you would do the final calculation / logic and then return the expected result.

This information, and more, can be found on the MSDN page for [Requirements for CLR User-Defined Aggregates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms131051.aspx).